# Перебор всех кнопок | WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, ХэшКодовцы.

Вопрос уже поднимался, знаю, но не могу реализовать.

Цель: на главном окне 81 кнопка. При том кнопки находятся на разном уровне вложенности (не знаю, правильно сказал ли). Нужно каждой кнопке в окне задать один и тот же метод для Click.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

P.S. `foreach (Control c in this.Controls)` - не пойдет (не находит `this.Controls`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно для окна задать стиль кнопки по умолчанию, в котором прописать обработчик события для всех кнопок.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="Button_Click"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Благодарю!